# Depth First search path

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search, backtracking

My lecturer gave me these as the answers for Depth first questions and I think they are wrong. 
Tree graph and search tree

[image]

the question is:

1. For the graph in the lecture notes, mark the order in which nodes are searched (generated) when using:

a) Depth-first search.

b) Depth-first, backtracking search.

c) Breadth-first search.

the answer to these questions is apparently,

1.
 a) Depth-first search.
a, b, d, d, e, l, c, f, h, n, p, q, z, j, m, z, k, q, p, q, z, z, c, f, h, n, p, q, z.

b) Depth-first, backtracking search.
a, b, d, c, f, h, n, p, q, z, e, j, m, z, l, k, p, q, z, q, z, d, c, f, h, n, p, q, z.

c) Breadth-first search.
a, b, d, d, e, l, c, c, j, k, q, f, f, m, p, z, h, n, h, n, z, q, p, p, z, q, q, z, z.

me and three other student cannot figure out how he got these.

Comment: 1. a) Depth-first search seems to be wrong. It should be:
a, b, d, c,f,h,n,p,q,z,e,j,m,z,i,k,p,q,z,q,z, ....

Comment: Thats depth search with backtracking as u can see in the second answer 1B, or are you implying they are both the same?